# How to easily get all Refs for a given Commit?

Tags: libgit2sharp

Is there an easy way to find all References (e.g. Tags) for a given Commit?
For example:

```
using( Repository repo = new Repository( path_to_repo ) )
{
    foreach( Commit commit in repo.Commits )
    {
        List<Reference> assignedRefs = commit.Refs; // <- how to do this?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below retrieves all the references that can reach the selected commit.

```
using( Repository repo = new Repository( path_to_repo ) )
{
    foreach( Commit commit in repo.Commits )
    {
        IEnumerable<Reference> refs =
               repo.Refs.ReachableFrom(new[] { commit });
    }
}
```

If you want to only retrieve `Tag`s, the method exposes an overload to help you with this.

```
using( Repository repo = new Repository( path_to_repo ) )
{
    var allTags = repo.Refs.Where(r => r.IsTag()).ToList();

    foreach( Commit commit in repo.Commits )
    {
        IEnumerable<Reference> refs =
               repo.Refs.ReachableFrom(allTags, new[] { commit });
    }
}
```

**Note:** This code will retrieve all refs that either directly point to the chosen commit or point to an ancestor of this commit. In this sense, it behaves similarly to the **[git rev-list](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)** command.

Comment: The call to `repo.Refs.ReachableFrom` is very slow. I guess I have to get all Refs once and map them into a dictionary if I want to display a list of commits along with its refs (like `git log --decorate`)?

Comment: ReachableFrom() will indeed perform many revwalks (one for each passed in ref to examine).

Comment: Oh! I see. You don't care about reachable commits. You only need the commits that are directly pointed at by a reference. In this case, keeping a copy of the Refs would be the way to go. Beware of the Tags (and their potentially chaining behavior), see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808208) to properly tackle this. I'll properly update my answer in the next few days to provide you with a more detailed piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

As @user1130329 pointed out, going through all refs multiple times can be very expensive. Just as an alternative, this is what I have done here for a similar case:

```cs
logs = _repo.Commits
    .QueryBy(filter)
    .Select(c => new LogEntry
    {
        Id = c.Id.Sha,
        // other fields
    })
    .ToList();

var logsDictionary = logs.ToDictionary(d => d.Id);

_repo.Refs
    .Where(r => r.IsTag || r.IsLocalBranch)
    .ForEach(r =>
    {
        if (r.IsTag) logsDictionary.GetValueOrDefault(r.TargetIdentifier)?.Tags.Add(r.CanonicalName);
        if (r.IsLocalBranch) logsDictionary.GetValueOrDefault(r.TargetIdentifier)?.Heads.Add(r.CanonicalName);
    });
```