# LibGit2Sharp Find release for commit

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

In github I can view a commit and view all the releases it was part of.

I am trying to do something similar with `LibGit2Sharp`. I can find a commit and I can find a release, but I can't see how to tell if a commit was in a release or not.

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Release` is a GitHub concept. It's built on the git concept of a `Tag` and enriched with a  styled Release Notes and downloadable assets.

From the LibGit2Sharp perspective, what you're after is finding all the tags that point to a specific commit.

The SO question **[What's the fastest way to find Tags pointing to Commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19808208)** deals exactly with this.