# How to check if HEAD is tagged

Tags: git, rust

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
cd /tmp
cargo new --bin foo
cd foo
cat > src/main.rs << EOF
extern crate git2;

use git2::{Repository, ObjectType};

fn main() {
    let repo = Repository::open("/tmp/foo").unwrap();
    let git_ref = repo.head().unwrap();
    git_ref.peel(ObjectType::Tag).unwrap();
}
EOF
cargo add git2
git add .
git commit --message "foo"
git tag foo
cargo run
```

I get a panic:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { code: -12, klass: 11, message: "the git_object of id \'33030777b0a6b61f631be64c3f1cb7d66b8f3082\' can not be successfully peeled into a tag (git_otype=4)." }', /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:906:4

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Francis Gagné says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502215/155423), you can't get to a tag from a commit — you have to go the other way. Additionally, there can be multiple tags for a commit. The appropriate data structure is a mapping of commit references to a list of tag references:

```
extern crate git2;

use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use git2::Repository;

fn main() {
    let repo = Repository::open("/tmp/foo").unwrap();
    let tag_names = repo.tag_names(None).unwrap();

    let tag_and_refs = tag_names.iter()
        .flat_map(|name| name)
        .flat_map(|name| {
            let full_tag = format!("refs/tags/{}", name);
            repo.find_reference(&full_tag).map(|reference| (name, reference))
        });

    let mut refs_to_tags = BTreeMap::new();
    for (name, reference) in tag_and_refs {
        refs_to_tags.entry(reference).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(name);
    }

    let git_ref = repo.head().unwrap();

    let tags = &refs_to_tags[&git_ref];
    println!("tags for HEAD: {:?}", tags);
}
```

This only handles lightweight tags, which is what your example uses.

See also:

- [What's the fastest way to find Tags pointing to Commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19808208/155423)

Comment: why choice of BTreeMap, instead of HashMap

Comment: @Tshepang because only `BTreeMap` compiles. Try it for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

`HEAD` usually doesn't refer to a tag; it refers to another ref (e.g. `refs/heads/master`), which refers to a commit, which refers to a tree.

*Peeling*, as I understand it, is the process of dereferencing objects referenced by other objects or by references. However, since `HEAD` doesn't refer to a tag, you can't peel `HEAD` and expect to obtain a tag.

---

Git has two separate notions of *tags*. *Tag references* are just references under `refs/tags/`. *Annotated tags* are objects in the Git database, just like commits, trees and blobs are. Tag references can refer to any kind of object, but usually they'll refer to either commits or tag objects.

Whether you're after annotated tags or just any kind of tag, the first step is the same: you have to iterate on the references in `refs/tags/` and check if any of them peels to the same commit as `HEAD` peels to. If you're interested in annotated tags specifically, you can check if the tag reference peels to a tag object.